# Intuition behind MLE - Why is the MLE of inverse theta function the maximum X and not the minimum.

Tags: self-learning, maximum-likelihood

So I'm trying to understand why the MLE of $\theta$ for $$f_X(x) =\frac{1}{\theta}, \ \ 0\leq x\leq\theta$$ intuitively. For reference, I am using [Example 5 from this paper](https://people.missouristate.edu/songfengzheng/Teaching/MTH541/Lecture%20notes/MLE.pdf) that I found online. The answer says that it is $\hat{\theta}_{MLE}= max(X_1...X_n)= x_{(n)}$

Given a parameter $\theta$, we are trying to find the most likely value of theta. So in essence we want to find the location in which the likelihood function $L$ is at its maximum. Here is $L$:

$$L(\theta) = \frac{1}{\theta^n}$$

Now, if we look at this crude plot of $L(\theta)$ below, we see that at $x_{(n)}$ $L$ is actually at its minimum value. So why do we choose $x_{(n)}$ and not $x_{(1)}$? shouldn't we want the point where our plot is at its maximum? Repeating my question again.. if we are trying to find the value of $\theta$ that is **most likely**, shouldn't it be the value for which the likelihood function is at **its highest** i.e. $x_{(1)}$?

[[image: Plot of <span class=]$L(\theta)$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDdIz.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability distribution here is the uniform distribution on $[0,\theta]$. That means that if we observe some collection of values $X_i$ from it, $\theta$ must be $\ge$ all of them. The maximum of the $X_i$ is the smallest $\theta$ that can possibly result in our observed values; since this smallest possible $\theta$ gives the highest probabilities, it's the MLE.

Short version: we don't take the minimum because the minimum is impossible.

Comment: Ok, so just so that I understand correctly, the part where we I said we are trying to maximize $L$ is true, right? If our support was something like: $[\theta,\inf]$, we would say that the MLE is $x_{(1)}$, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Of course, we would need infinitely many observations to have infinite support, so that case isn't something that will come up in practice.

Comment: Ok, cool that makes sense. Thanks!